# django: How to migrate models?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a doubt in the Django models section, if I write some models in another python file like model123.py, within the same app, then how to migrate those models or how to use them?

Comment: Why did you use another file, not models.py file?

Comment: I know models.py is used to add models,
but if there is any chance to add models in another python file then how to use it, that's my doubt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could that file in the `models.py` file like the following.

```
from .model123 import *
```

Then you can make migrations for that model too.